# Visual Basic executing a python script

Tags: python, vb.net

I am using Visual Basic to create a program to run a python script. I want it to be like "shell("c:\test\script.py arg1 arg2")" and then in the python script it would be like 
"print arg1  print arg2" so like the python script recieves the arguments and it prints them. Also would there be anyway to run the python script in idle from vb.net? Or would there be anyway to get the data being printed on the python, and list it on a listbox on the vb.net form? Thanks

Comment: Horrible coding practice IMHO, I'd embed Python in a DLL. But I guess you want to make the python files executable by the Python.exe on your system. Something like shell("C:\Python\python.exe c:\test\script.py arg1 arg2") you should be cleared.

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't even start the python executable.

Comment: the error? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used VB.net for such purpose, but you can create a exe of your python script following link:

http://pc2solution.blogspot.in/2013/12/python-make-standalone-exe-for-any.html

and then you can run that exe using

```
process.start(path of exe)
```

Comment: But how would i send arg1 to the python script? So it would be like process.start("pathofexe arg1")? And then in the python it would be print arg1? Or is it different?

Comment: process.start("pathof.exe arg1") should do.